# Spring Cloud Dataflow - composed-task-runner doesn't start second task

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow pipeline consisting of two sequential batch jobs. The first batch gets completed successfully, but the second one doesn't start.
I have started Dataflow server with the embedded H2 DB. I've pointed Spring Batch to the same H2 instance via *application.properties*. After the first step in my pipeline gets completed, I can see batch execution logs in that same DB instance.
My *composed-task-runner* application seems getting the Dataflow's datasource correctly. I can see it inherits it from Dataflow server and props are shown in the Dashboard's task execution section.
There are no errors in the logs. Only log entries from successful execution of the first batch.
My TASK_EXECUTION entries:

[image]

What could be the problem? And why there are two entries in the TASK_EXECUTION table for the first step? Per the task_name - these entries belong to the first batch step only.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address this issue by re-building my batch task using Spring Initialzr. Initially I was trying to use spring-cloud-task-app-starters as the base for my work, and probably it is not the right way of building Dataflow tasks.